# Extract the complete sentences with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a random from a file to extract some phrases. But many of them appear incomplete:

**Script:**

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xls')

column = df['alim_nom_fr']

data = column.drop_duplicates(keep="last").reset_index(drop=True)

data_random = data.sample(10) 

print(data_random)
```

Output:

```
2794    Plat légumes, avec féculent et viande/poisson,...
1737                                          Lompe, crue
2518    Beurre ou assimilé à teneur en matière grasse ...
1954        Fromage blanc nature, gourmand, 8% MG environ
1316                                    Porc, jarret, cru
508            Tomate, pulpe et peau, rôtie/cuite au four
1233                  Gibier à poil, cuit (aliment moyen)
1080    Gaufre croustillante (fine ou sèche), nature o...
217                                          Pissaladière
2523                                      Beurre de cacao
```

My problem is these phrases:

```
2794    Plat légumes, avec féculent et viande/poisson,...
2518    Beurre ou assimilé à teneur en matière grasse ...
1080    Gaufre croustillante (fine ou sèche), nature o...
```

Would it be possible to extract the complete sentences?

**Small dataset example:**

```
ssgrp_nom_fr    alim_code   alim_nom_fr
salades         25600       Céleri rémoulade, préemballé
salades         25601       Salade de thon et légumes, appertisée
salades         25602       Salade composée avec viande ou poisson
salades         25605       Champignon à la grecque
salades         25606       Salade de pommes de terre maison
salades         25608       Taboulé ou Salade de couscous, préemballé
salades         25609       Salade de pomme de terre à la piémontaise, préemballée
salades         25614       Salade de riz
salades         25615       Salade de pâtes, végétarienne
salades         25616       Crudité, sans assaisonnement (aliment moyen)
salades         25619       Salade de pâtes aux légumes, avec poisson ou viande
salades         25628       Salade César au poulet (salade verte, fromage, croûtos, sauce)
salades         26259       Salade de chou ou Coleslaw, avec sauce, préemballée
salades         26269       Taboulé ou Salade de couscous au poulet, préemballé
soupes          25900       Soupe aux lentilles, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25901       Soupe à la volaille et aux légumes, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25903       Soupe aux légumes variés, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25904       Soupe de poissons et / ou crustacés, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25905       Soupe aux légumes variés, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25907       Soupe aux poireaux et pommes de terre, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25908       Soupe à la volaille et aux vermicelles, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25909       Bouillon de viande et légumes type pot-au-feu, prêt à consommer
soupes          25910       Soupe à l'oignon, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25912       Soupe aux champignons, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25913       Soupe à la carotte, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25914       Soupe à la tomate, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25915       Soupe chorba frik, à base de viande et de frik
soupes          25916       Soupe minestrone, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25917       Soupe au pistou, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25919       Soupe de poissons et / ou crustacés, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25923       Soupe asiatique, avec pâtes, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25924       Soupe marocaine, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25925       Soupe aux poireaux et pommes de terre, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25928       Soupe à la volaille et aux légumes, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25930       Bouillon de boeuf, déshydraté reconstitué
soupes          25932       Soupe aux asperges, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25933       Soupe à la tomate et aux vermicelles, préemballée à réchauffer
soupes          25934       Soupe aux céréales et aux légumes, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25935       Soupe à la tomate, déshydratée reconstituée
soupes          25936       Soupe aux champignons, déshydratée reconstituée
```

I just want to have the complete sentences without the **...**

Comment: Use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)`

Comment: You could also use: data.ix[2794] data.ix[2518] and data.ix[1080] to access individual elements of the frame which print the total sentence.